# Create a tikz diagram which includes mathbb

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I create this diagram in latex?
[image]

I would like to do it with the `tikz` package, as I want to annotate the edges.

I tried with this template, but it does not allow me to add `\mathbb` elements inside it. http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/commutative-diagram-tikz/

I am sorry that I am not able to better explain my problem, I have never worked with stackexchange and I am a latex beginner.. Thank you for your help.

Edit:

**What I have so far**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=3em,column sep=4em,minimum width=2em]
  {
 $\mathbb{R}^2$ & $R^2$ \\
 A_t & A \\
 $R^2$ & $R^2$ \\};
\path[-stealth]
(m-1-1) edge node [left] {$\mathcal{B}_X$} (m-2-1)
        edge [double] node [below] {$\mathcal{B}_t$} (m-1-2)
(m-2-1.east|-m-2-2) edge node [below] {$\mathcal{B}_T$}
        node [above] {$\exists$} (m-2-2)
(m-1-2) edge node [right] {$\mathcal{B}_T$} (m-2-2)
        edge [dashed,-] (m-2-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**My packages**

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage,amsfonts,mathpazo}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\pagestyle{empty}
```

**The Result**
[image]

Edit2:

The Issue is solved, I used mathmode (dollar signs) inside the diagram which I should not have, removing them solved the issue. Thank you everyone who helped!

Comment: Add `\usepackage{amssymb}` to your preamble.  `\mathbb` is not provided by default in LaTeX, but must be loaded with an external package, in this case `amssymb`.  The example you cite does not provide it, so you must invoke it explicitly.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please post some minimal example code, so we can see exactly what you have tried.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by annotate? You want to insert large amounts of text pointing to the edges, or directly on the edges?

Comment: There is no reason to use this method to draw the diagram, the `tikz-cd` package  provides a nice interface to draw these. BTW: make your sniplet into one single thing, a lot easier for others to copy and test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces exactly what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=3em,column sep=4em,minimum width=2em]
  {
     \mathbb{F}^m & \mathbb{F}^n\\
     V & W \\
     \mathbb{F}^m&\mathbb{F}^n\\
 };
  \path[-stealth]
    (m-1-1) edge (m-2-1)
            edge node [above] {$A_1$} (m-1-2)
    (m-1-2) edge (m-2-2)
    (m-2-1) edge node [above] {$L$} (m-2-2)
    (m-3-1) edge (m-2-1)
            edge node [above] {$A_2$} (m-3-2)
    (m-3-2) edge (m-2-2)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you really much, I found my error: I tried using math mode inside the diagram, which is apparently not needed, and disable the already activated math mode, resulting in my error.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that very simply with `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
%

\[ \begin{tikzcd}[arrows = {-Stealth}]
\mathbb{F}^m \rar["A_1"] \dar & \mathbb{F}^n \dar \\%
V \rar["L"] & W \\
\mathbb{F}^m \rar["A_2"] \uar & \mathbb{F}^n \uar
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am already using the other answer to realize my idea, and if I am honest, I can't exactly see how this is supposed to be easier. Nevermind, thank you for your help!

Comment: The code is much shorter, that's the main point. Anyway, it's based on TikZ.

Comment: Ease and difficulty are personal opinions :):):) By the way, +1!